# How to create iob tags for a sentence?

Tags: tagging, named-entity-recognition, bert-language-model

I have a dataset for NER in which I have to do POS tagging and IOB tagging, but I don't understand the concept or method of how iob tags are created. Even CoNLL is pretagged.